How to get unique properties like "ItemType" , "HelpText" or others as seen from the inspect tool for an element?
In order to to automate a GUI application using pywinauto I am trying to get hold of properties like ItemType , HelpText and many more which we see in the inspect tool. But I don't seem to get hold of the same.
Usually we use properties inside .child_window() methods like title , auto_id, control_type to locate an element which i am able to do.
But at the end of an action that I perform i want to retrieve properties like ItemType  so I can assert that the action has been performed successfully.
app = Application(backend = "uia").start(app_path, timeout=10)

I am able to locate the element using the below:
tab = dlg.child_window(title = "TabGroup", control_type = "TabItem")
I tried using .get_properties() method which gives me "class_name", "texts" , "control_id", "is_keyboard_focusable" and others. However this doesn't serve my purpose.
I am particularly interested in getting the below properties from inspect :
ItemType:   "Section Group"
HelpText:   "Navigates into a section group"
PositionInSet:  4
SizeOfSet:  5

However it would be great if I could get to know how to get all the properties that we see from inspect tool.
I wonder if there is any other code property name that or method name that could give me the results?
